# Google Cloud Storage FUSE - Using gcsfuse fills up local instance memory

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I've been using gcsfuse (FUSE) for some weeks and everything was running smoothly until my instance disk(10GB) got filled up out of nowhere.

I was trying to identify the cause and erasing some temporal files and found out that unmounting the bucket fixed the issue.

It's supposed to upload to the cloud right? So why is it taking up space as if it was counted as local instance space?

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a reason why you would see this behaviour.

Pasting from the gcsfuse doc
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

> Local storage: Objects that are new or modified will be stored in
>   their entirety in a local temporary file until they are closed or
>   synced. When working with large files, be sure you have enough local
>   storage capacity for temporary copies of the files, particularly if
>   you are working with Google Compute Engine instances. For more
>   information, see the readme documentation.

Comment: Thanks! this makes sense, have enough HDD for temp files